# Error in connecting to Oracle using ODBC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect my Visual Studio 2010 application with Oracle database using ODBC. This is what I've done so far:

1. Added a new Dat Source Name from Administrative tools->ODBC Data Sources.
   I selected Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 as the driver. I used the service name given in the TNS Service Name drop down. I tested the connection and it was succesful. **Does this mean I was able to connect to my database from my system or does it mean the driver is working correctly.**
2. In visual studio's server explorer I selected add connection. I selected Microsoft ODBC Data Source as the Data Source and slected my DSN from the drop down. Gave the User name and password. When I try to test the connection i get the following errors:

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

**[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed**

What I am doing wrong. Do I need to install any new drivers or dlls? Please do help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC maintains separate sets of sources for 32 and 64bit applications. Compare C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've said here.

Comment: Connections created with default admin tool are invisible to 32-bit apps. If your application is 32-bit then you have to create ODBC connection with ODBC Administrator tool whose full path is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.